# Problem with determinants and polynomials $\left|\begin{smallmatrix}P(a)&&Q(a)&&R(a)\\P(b)&&Q(b)&&R(b)\\P(c)&&Q(c)&&R(c)\end{smallmatrix}\right|=1$

Tags: determinant

Let $P,Q,R$ be polynomials of degree less than 2 and $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$

such that
$D(a,b,c)=\begin{vmatrix}P(a)&&Q(a)&&R(a)\\P(b)&&Q(b)&&R(b)\\P(c)&&Q(c)&&R(c)\end{vmatrix}=1$

Prove that $D(1,b,c)+D(a,1,c)+D(a,b,1)=D(a,b,c)$.

My approach:
Consider $P(x)=mx^2+nx+p, Q(x)=dx^2+ex+f, R(x)=rx^2+sx+t$
Then we have
$D(a,b,c)=-\begin{vmatrix}m&&n&&p\\ d&&e&&f\\r&&s&&t\end{vmatrix}\dot{}\begin{vmatrix}1&&1&&1\\ a&&b&&c\\a^2&&b^2&&c^2\end{vmatrix}$

Then we need to show that 
$\begin{vmatrix}1&&1&&1\\ a&&b&&c\\a^2&&b^2&&c^2\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}1&&1&&1\\ 1&&b&&c\\1&&b^2&&c^2\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}1&&1&&1\\ a&&1&&c\\a^2&&1&&c^2\end{vmatrix}+ \begin{vmatrix}1&&1&&1\\ a&&b&&1\\a^2&&b^2&&1\end{vmatrix}$

I did this by considering the system of equations

$x+y+z=1 \\ ax+by+cz=1 \\a^2x+b^2y+c^2z=1$

and using Cramer rule.
I am interested if there is another approach.

Comment: You wrote that the degree of $P, Q, R$ is less than two, but then assumed them to be quadratic in your approach. Which is it?

Comment: I didn;t assume this, the leading coefficients can be zero so the degree can be lower

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$$D(x,b,c)+D(a,x,c)+D(a,b,x)-D(a,b,c)$$
It is a quadratic polynomial in $x$, put $x=a$. The expression becomes,
$$D(a,b,c)+D(a,a,c)+D(a,b,a)-D(a,b,c)$$
The second and third terms are zero due to identical rows, and first and third cancel. So $x=a$ is a root of this quadratic polynomial. Similarly, $x=b$ and $x=c$ are also roots of this. Since, it is a quadratic polynomial having three roots, it is identically zero for all $x\in \mathbb R$, hence holds for $x=1$.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Nice, but needs extra handling of the case when two of $a,b,c $ are equal.

Comment: @darij grinberg, That cannot occur, otherwise $D(a,b,c)=0$